# NSFetchedResultsController that contains objects from a relation

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `NSManagedObject` with related objects. The relation is described by a keyPath.

Now I want to display these related objects in a table view. Of course I could just take the `NSSet` with these objects as a data source, but I'd prefer to refetch the objects with a `NSFetchedResultsController` to benefit from its features.

How can I create a predicate that describes these objects?

Comment: Please describe the entities and relationships, and what exactly you want to display.

Comment: That should not matter. I am looking on a generic solution based on the object and the relation key path.

Answer (score 13):

To display the related objects of a given object with a fetched results controller,
you would use the *inverse relationship* in the predicate. For example:

[image]

To display the children related to a given parent, use a fetched results controller
with the following fetch request:

```
Parent *theParent = ...;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Child"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent = %@", theParent];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

For nested relationships, just use the inverse relationships in inverted order. Example:

[image]

To display the streets of a given country:

```
Country *theCountry = ...;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Street"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"city.country = %@", theCountry];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: How exactly do I get the inverse relation, especially if I have a key path with multiple elements?

Comment: Please see my own answer for a universal approach to get the key path. It seems a bit complicated, but I can't find a simpler solution with the core data API.

Comment: @MartinR what will help if there is parent and no child object. I think then this relation will not show parent object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Martin, you gave me important information.

To generically get the key path I have found the following implementation:

```
    // assume to have a valid key path and object
    NSString *keyPath;
    NSManagedObject *myObject;

    NSArray *keys = [keyPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = myObject.entity;
    NSMutableArray *inverseKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:keys.count];
    // for the predicate we will need to know if we're dealing with a to-many-relation
    BOOL isToMany = NO;
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        NSRelationshipDescription *inverseRelation = [[[entity relationshipsByName] valueForKey:key] inverseRelationship];
        // to-many on multiple hops is not supported.
        if (isToMany) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: Cannot create a valid inverse relation for: %@. Hint: to-many on multiple hops is not supported.", keyPath);
            return nil;
        }
        isToMany = inverseRelation.isToMany;
        NSString *inverseKey = [inverseRelation name];
        [inverseKeys insertObject:inverseKey atIndex:0];
    }
    NSString *inverseKeyPath = [inverseKeys componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
    // now I can construct the predicate
    if (isToMany) {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K = %@", inverseKeyPath, self.dataObject];
    }
    else {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", inverseKeyPath, self.dataObject];
    }
```

**Update:** I changed the predicate format so that it also supports many-to-many relations.

**Update 2** This is getting more complex: I need to check my inverse relation if it is to-many and use different predicates. I updated the code example above.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"city.country = '%@'", theCountry];
```

You miss ' ' in predicateWithFormat string. Now it work.

Comment: This is not correct. With quotation marks `'%@'` the %@ is *not expanded* by the argument.